# Java Swing component randomly being rendered in wrong place

Tags: java, kotlin, swing

I am currently developing a desktop app with Kotlin and Swing and having trouble with a `JTextField` randomly rendering in the wrong place. I have a login form and when I click on the `JComboBox` after entering information into the `JTextField`, the textfield renders where the combo box should be. This issue only seems to be occurring on Windows. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

This is what it looks like before focusing:
[image]

And this is what it looks like after focusing:
[image]

Here is my code for the combobox:

`SelectDistrictBox.kt`

```
import com.github.weisj.jsvg.attributes.ViewBox
import com.ishaan.gsdesktop.ui.Colors
import com.ishaan.gsdesktop.ui.Cursors
import com.ishaan.gsdesktop.ui.SVGIcons
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent
import javax.swing.JComboBox

class SelectDistrictBox : JComboBox<String>() {
    init {
        model = SelectDistrictBoxModel()
        setUI(SelectDistrictBoxUI())
        setRenderer(SelectDistrictBoxRenderer())

        addMouseListener(object : MouseAdapter() {
            override fun mouseEntered(e: MouseEvent?) {
                cursor = Cursors.HAND
            }

            override fun mouseExited(e: MouseEvent?) {
                cursor = Cursors.HAND
            }
        })
            isOpaque = true
    }

    companion object {
        // This requireNotNull should probably be changed eventually.
        private val CHEVRON_DOWN_ICON = requireNotNull(SVGIcons.getChevronDownIcon())
        private val CHEVRON_UP_ICON = requireNotNull(SVGIcons.getChevronUpIcon())

        private const val WIDTH = 620
        private const val RENDER_WIDTH = 608
        private const val HEIGHT = 40
    }

    override fun getPreferredSize() = Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        val g2 = g as Graphics2D
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON)

        // Draw the box for the Component
//        drawBackgroundBox(g2)

        // Draw the selected item
        drawSelectedItemLabel(g2)

        // Draw the arrow icon
        drawArrowIcon(g2)
    }

    private fun drawBackgroundBox(g2: Graphics2D) {
        g2.color = Colors.TEXTBOX_FILL
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, RENDER_WIDTH, HEIGHT, 40, 40)
    }

    private fun drawSelectedItemLabel(g2: Graphics2D) {
        g2.color = Colors.TEXT_SECONDARY
        g2.font = Font("Poppins", Font.PLAIN, 14)

        g2.drawString(model.selectedItem as String, 20F, 24.3F)
    }

    private fun drawArrowIcon(g2: Graphics2D) {
        CHEVRON_DOWN_ICON.render(this, g2, ViewBox(RENDER_WIDTH - 34F, HEIGHT - 28.5F, 16F, 16F))
    }
}
```

`SelectDistrictBoxUI.kt`

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import java.awt.Rectangle
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing.JComponent
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI

class SelectDistrictBoxUI : BasicComboBoxUI() {

    override fun paint(g: Graphics?, c: JComponent?) {
        val g2 = g as Graphics2D

        g2.dispose()
    }

    override fun paintCurrentValueBackground(g: Graphics?, bounds: Rectangle?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
    }

    override fun paintCurrentValue(g: Graphics?, bounds: Rectangle?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
    }

    override fun createArrowButton(): JButton {
        // We need to return an empty button.
        val btn = JButton()
        btn.isVisible = false
        return btn
    }

    override fun createPopup() = SelectDistrictBoxPopup(comboBox)
}
```

Comment: Why does `SelectDistrictBoxUI`.`paint()` call `dispose()` on the Graphics context?

Comment: I'm a relative beginner to swing, and didn't know that I wasn't supposed to do that. But removing that didn't seem to solve the problem.